# RTMP with Google Chromecast

Tags: google-cast

I was wondering if there is any way to cast an RTMP audio and/or video stream? I've created a receiver app, whitelisted it, and able to access it on my Chromecast. I tried to embed an SWF object but it appears that the Chromecast does not support flash natively like this. Is there any workaround?

I see the docs for [supported media types](https://developers.google.com/cast/supported_media_types) and it doesn't list RTMP so I'm thinking it's a no-go, other than doing some on-the-fly stream protocol translation from RTMP to MP3 or such on another server.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, receiver apps can only work with HTML5 media, which doesn't support the RTMP protocol (also keep in mind that RTMP is not a media format, but a media transfer protocol which can carry various different container formats and audio/video codecs); as Chromecast requires HTML5, it also requires HTTP as the transfer protocol).

You could set up a proxy as your receiver app that would consume an RTMP stream and then re-cast it as an http-based HTML5 media resource. There wouldn't be a lot of overhead if you didn't have to do any transcoding (say, for example, your RTMP stream was H.264 video with MP3 audio), but it could get messy having to wrap all the media resource handling that Chromecast can do just to talk to an RTMP server. It would likely be much easier to work with HTML5 video from the get-go.

Comment: Any changes to this scenario?